# Automatic fill / Dropdown list with data validation if more than 1 option

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with the following columns:

NODE NAME, NODE ID, PARENT NODE, PARENT NODE ID

PARENT NODE ID cell shows the ID of the parent node and it is automatically filled once PARENT NODE is filled (It is done by a VLOOKUP into the first two columns: NODE NAME, NODE ID).

The problem is there are some nodes with the same name and then when typing PARENT NODE, PARENT NODE ID has different options. I would like to have:

- If there is only one NODE NAME with the name displayed in PARENT NODE -> Display the PARENT NODE ID directly
- If parent node REFERS to a NODE that has nodes with the same name, then a Data validation list with the different PARENT NODE IDs that have that name is displayed.

Right now I only implemented the first option (on VBA):

```
Range("EditParentNodeId").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(EditParentNode,Schema[[Node name]:[Node ID]],2),"""")"
```

Could you help me with the code for having both options?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: please show us a snapshot of the table and your entire code

Comment: See the above picture @MassimoGriffani (code is too long)